# Design Time property for user control

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I have the user control with the following property

```
<EditOptions AllowEditing="true" AllowAdding="true" AllowDeleting="true" />
```

How to give the above property in design time as "EditOptions".

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i have achieved by declaring the attribute "**[TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))]**" for the EditOption class. Now i am able to give the above property in design time for custom control.